# When I am using Moovweb for a mobile site, does all of the request (even desktop) get passed through the Moovweb servers?

Tags: moovweb

I understand that Moovweb servers sit in front of my Desktop site load balancer. It seems like all of my traffic would have to be passed through the Moovweb servers. Does this cause a hit on performance of the desktop site?

Answer (score 1):

Because the moovSDK does a request to your desktop and any desktopjs it does have an extremely slight impact on desktop performance. However, I would not say it is a negative impact, it's more views! You do not have to scale both a mobile and a desktop site, instead we worry about scaling your mobile site.

So while it can have an impact on your desktop site, the fact of the matter is, the imact is less overall than it would be to run your own desktop and mobile site!